# install/uninstall issue with pywin32

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying simple uninstall/install for this package and getting following error followed by successful uninstallation.

```
python -m pip uninstall pywin32
...
Successfully uninstalled pywin32-227
...
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\~0win32_system32\\pythoncom36.dll'
```

I tried following things:

1. Run the uninstallation as admin
2. moved my pip version to `20.0.2` as latest version `21.0.1` was giving same issue

**Full traceback below:**

```
    ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 82, in run
    uninstall_pathset.commit()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 450, in commit
    self._moved_paths.commit()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 290, in commit
    save_dir.cleanup()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 175, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 136, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 500, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python36\\lib\\site- 
    packages\\~1win32_system32\\pythoncom36.dll'
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem on my Windows machine.

Try this

```
pip install --user pywin32
```

Plus, to upgrade `pip`

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```